# Parsing bulk conversion from JSON to CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am using the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204735/converting-a-very-large-json-file-to-csv) in Python 3 to convert ~30,000 json files to a csv.

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
for fname in glob("*.json"):  # Reads all json from the current directory
    with open(fname) as j:
        f.write(str(json.load(j)))
        f.write('\n')
```

The json files are timestamps and values, for example `{"1501005600":956170,"1501048800":970046,...`

The output currently is

[image: <code>timestamp: value</code>].

How can I put each in their own respective cells so the output is [image]?

I have tried many approaches with csv.writer but I cannot figure this out.

**UPDATE**

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:  
for fname in glob("*.json"):  
    with open(fname) as j: 
        values = json.load(j)  
        for k, v in values.items():  
            f.write("{},{},".format(str(k), str(v)))
```

Parsing is correct but each .json file is on one row now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me get to the bottom of this, hope this may help others.

```
with open('[insert].csv', 'w') as f:  
for fname in glob("*.json"):  
    with open(fname) as j:  
        values = json.load(j)  
        for k, v in values.items():  
            f.write("{},{},".format(str(k), str(v)))  
    f.write('\n')
```