# parse json with nested field (Kotlin)

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin

I have 2 examples:

1. Json file - example.json:

   ```
   {
       "users": [
           {
               "id": "1",
               "name": "ABC",
               "email": "abc@gmail.com",
               "contact": {
                   "mobile1": "0123456789",
                   "mobile2": "0123456789",
                   "mobile3": "0123456789"
               }
           },
           {
               "id": "2",
               "name": "XYZ",
               "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
               "contact": {
                   "mobile1": "0123456789",
                   "mobile2": "0123456789",
                   "mobile3": "0123456789"
               }
           }
        ]
    }
   ```
2. Json file - [data.json] (https://github.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/blob/master/data/data.json)

For parsing this json-files I use function:

```
 fun getJsonDataFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String? {
    val jsonString: String
    try {
        jsonString = context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        System.out.println("jsonString" + jsonString)
    } catch (ioException: IOException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return jsonString
}
```

In First cause I have:

```
try {
        val obj = JSONObject(getJsonDataFromAsset(this,"example.json"))
        val itemsArray = obj.getJSONArray("users")
        .....}
```

It's OK!

In Second I have:

```
try {
        val obj = JSONObject(getJsonDataFromAsset(this,"data.json"))
        val itemsArray = obj.getJSONArray("item")
        .....}
```

I have trouble - not value for item.

If I use field "channel":

```
try {
        val obj = JSONObject(getJsonDataFromAsset(this,"example.json"))
        val itemsArray = obj.getJSONArray("channel")
        .....}
```

I get an error message:

> "W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"title":"TED Theme: The
> Creative Spark"...."

What's wrong?

Comment: Make sure your JSON is valid, try https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: JSON is valid. I checked.

Comment: The root of `data.json` doesn't contain key `item`. You should first fetch `channel` from root and then `item` from `channel`

Comment: Ok. I try. But I can't get a valid Jsonobject from this file.

Comment: I think the second file - data.json is just too big to convert it. Almost 23000 lines is a bit much - is this obligatory?

Comment: Ok. How solve this problem?

Comment: I think you will have to divide the big file to some smaller ones, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204735/converting-a-very-large-json-file-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/master/data/data.json"
        val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
        val call = request.getItems(url)


               call.enqueue(object : Callback<GitResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<GitResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<GitResponse>, response: Response<GitResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        recyclerview.apply {
                            progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                            adapter = MyAdapter(response.body()?.channel?.item ?: listOf())

                            recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                            (adapter as MyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
    }
}
```